# Terminating asynchronous delegate threads when not complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have C# code here:

```
    dlgCardLimit dlg = new dlgCardLimit(GetCardLimit);
    IAsyncResult res = dlg.BeginInvoke(cardNo, null, null);
    res.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeOut);
    if (res.IsCompleted)
    {
        cardLimit = dlg.EndInvoke(res);
    }
    else
    {
        //Terminate the async thread.
    }
```

In "Else" case, how can I terminate the thread that **IAsyncResult** is pointing?

Comment: I assume you want to pop out a dialog/window from non-UI worker thread, and close it when there's no use response. Does this code even work for you? Does it show the dlg window? How do you synchronize it with the UI thread?

Answer (score 2):

Your `dlgCardLimit` class should have another method that would allow a graceful cancellation of the pending operation, such as Cancel or Close so as to give a chance for Gracefully handling the error. The thread on which this is running is hidden from you.

Checkout the [`Socket.EndReceive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b.aspx) for a similar pattern in cancelling a pending operation.